# Count consecutive letters

Tags: python, string, count

I want to count how many consecutive letters are in this string:

```
string=['S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'S']
```

The code should return the following:

```
[['S',1],['E',1],['S',1],['E',2],['N',3],['W',3],['S',1]]
```

I've tried the following code but it just didn't come out. Could someone help me? Thanks

```
S=0
N=0
W=0
E=0
result=[]
for k in string:
    if k=='S':
        S+=1
        result.append(['S',S])
    elif k=='N':
        N+=1
        result.append(['N',N])
    elif k=='W':
        W+=1
        result.append(['W',W])    
    elif k=='E':
        E+=1
        result.append(['E',E])
print(result)
```

Comment: Maybe you can print the output of command and let everyone know what kind of help you needed?  Also there is actually a simple way of doing what you want to do.... please look at Collections.Counter

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Counting consecutive characters in a string](/q/13197668/90527)

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html?highlight=itertools%20product#itertools.groupby):

```py
import itertools

string=['S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'S']

result = [[k, len(list(g))] for k, g in itertools.groupby(string)]
print(result)
```

Output:

```py
[['S', 1], ['E', 1], ['S', 1], ['E', 2], ['N', 3], ['W', 3], ['S', 1]]
```

Comment: This is more pythonic than the rest of the solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to compute consecutive elements not cumulative so keeping global trackers for each char is not useful and does not scale to new characters you can do

```
string=['S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'S']
prev = None
result=[]
for k in string:
    if prev and k == prev:
        result[-1][1]+=1
    else:
        result.append([k,1])
    prev = k
print(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

It is better to choose the type of result from the dictionary type.
Your code should look like this:

```py
string=['S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'S']

S=0 
N=0 
W=0 
E=0

result = {}
for k in string:
    if k=='S': 
        S+=1 
        result['S']=S 
    elif k=='N': 
        N+=1 
        result['N']=N 
    elif k=='W': 
        W+=1 
        result['W']=W     
    elif k=='E': 
        E+=1 
        result['E']=E 

print(result)
```

The result of executing the code is as follows:

```
{'S': 6, 'E': 6, 'N': 6, 'W': 6}
```

This [link](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html) provides good information about Data Structures in Python.

good luck.

Answer (score 0):

this code can help you and has no fixed letters.

```
string=['S', 'E', 'S', 'E', 'E', 'N', 'N', 'N', 'W', 'W', 'W', 'S']
result=[]
currentLetter=None
currentCount=0
for k in string:
    if currentLetter == None:
        currentLetter = k
        currentCount = 1  
    elif k == currentLetter:
        currentCount += 1
    
    if currentLetter != None and k != currentLetter:
        result.append([currentLetter, currentCount])
        currentLetter = k
        currentCount = 1
result.append([currentLetter, currentCount])
print(result)
```

You can navigate the array as in your code and:

- first time you find a letter (`currentLetter == None`) set the letter and start counting.
- when you find a different letter (`k != currentLetter`) add the couple (`[currentLetter, currentCount]`) to the result, change the `currentLetter` and reset the `currentCount`.
- finally, add the last letter to the result and print it out.

The result will be exactly that:
`[['S', 1], ['E', 1], ['S', 1], ['E', 2], ['N', 3], ['W', 3], ['S', 1]]`